# How to find server name in c-Panel?

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I am trying to find the server name of my website to connect it to a MySQL database. Using c-Panel with GoDaddy, none of the guides online have answers that actually work. I'd appreciate it if someone who knows what he is doing could kindly guide me to my golden fleece.
P.S, I am using c-Panel version 11.58.0.19.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to get in touch with their support to improve the helper. Each account can contain specific settings and different services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the website and the database hosted on the same server then you have to use localhost as the server name and that should work.

Try it .

Answer (score 0):

You can search for server information in whm where you will get all the necessary server information.